# Multiple where queries that involve isGreaterThan or isLessThan on different fields in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I need some help with using multiple where clauses for my query that involves "lessThan" and "greaterThan" on multiple fields. As an example let's say I need to find a restaurant with an average food price lower than 15 and with a rating higher than 3. To fetch that from Firestore I would code that as:

```
Query = Firestore.instance.where("avgPrice" , "<", 15).where("rating" , ">", 3).orderBy("rating");
```

Now according to the Firestore documentation this is not possible because:

> All where filters other than `whereEqualTo()` must be on the same field.

Is there any cost efficient work-around for this that doesn't require me to fetch all my data and is there any other SQL/NOSQL databases out there that can do this type of query themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says: you can only have relational operations on a single field.

You can either do the additional filtering client-side, or you can add additional fields that allow you to do the other filters with equality checks. For example:

```
Firestore.instance
  .where("avgPriceLessThan15", "=", true)
  .where("rating" , ">", 3)
  .orderBy("rating")
```

Comment: Is this the case with all NOSQL databases?

Comment: It is the case for Firestore, which is one of the NoSQL databases I happen to know well enough to answer. I intentionally did not answer about other databases as: 1) I might not know about them well enough, 2) recommending a database is off-topic on Stack Overflow.